# How do I pass an Array string data as parameter for Swagger API using a variable?

Tags: javascript

```js
  $("#nonjstest").click(function() { 
     $.ajax({
            url:"https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=sold",
            type: "GET",
            contentType:"application/json",
            success: function(data){
              alert(data[0].id) 
            }
          })
  
   })
```

Here, I am passing the required parameters directly in the URL `status=sold`.
I want to pass them via a variable instead, but it's not working. I've tried the following:

```js
var requiredata = ["status=sold"]


   $("#nonjstest").click(function() { 
     $.ajax({
            url:"https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus",
            type: "GET",
            data: requiredata,
            contentType:"application/json",
            success: function(data){
              alert(data[0].id) 
            }
          })
  
   })
```

The request itself is successful, but nothing is returned, meaning, the parameters are not passed correctly. What is the problem with the way I'm passing the Array string?

I've tried `stringifying` the data, but it didn't work either.

Why is it not working? How do I pass the array string data with a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending the params as an object instead of as an array:

```
    var requiredata = {
      status: 'sold'
    };


   $("#nonjstest").click(function() { 
     $.ajax({
            url:"https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/findByStatus",
            type: "GET",
            data: requiredata,
            contentType:"application/json",
            success: function(data){
              alert(data[0].id) 
            }
          })
  
   });
```

Another option would be to pass the params as a string but it's worse because you have to pass it already encoded.

[Check the docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more information.

Comment: It worked, but why? The requirement was an Array string, not JSON object?

Comment: The `data` config of the ajax admits an object, a string of an array, but if you pass an array jquery will pick the index as the param key, in your code it sent `0: "status=sold"`.

I encourage you to check [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more information.

And pleasse if I solved your question consider marking my answer as the accepted answer. Thanks